# Degree of Characteristic Polynomial of a Square Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

Let $A$ be a Square Matrix where $A \in M^C_{n \times n}$ and $P(x)$ be its characteristic polynomial.
$A$ is also nilpotent.

Is it true if $A$ is a matrix $A_{n, n} $ in the complex matrices field, which is nilpotent, then its characteristic polynomial has a degree $n^2$?

If it's not true, when does it happen? What are the conditions  to such case?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: The characteristic polynomial for an $n\times n$ matrix cannot have degree greater than $n$. 
As for actually calculating it for a nilpotent matrix, first try proving that the eigenvalues are zero.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial of an $n\times n$ matrix always has degree $n$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of a matrix is $\mathrm{det}(A-\lambda I)$, so this determinant will have one factor of $\lambda$ for each entry in the diagonal of $A - \lambda I$, so the degree of the characteristic polynomial of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is $n$ (corresponding to one multiple of $\lambda$ for each row (or column)).