# The Degree of the Determinant of a Linear Mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

If $L: V \rightarrow V$ should be a linear mapping, where dim$V = n$, does it necessarily follow that the degree of the characteristic polynomial of $L$ is $n$?

Comment: the straight answer is  yes

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457901/degree-of-characteristic-polynomial-im-a-square-matrix

Comment: $P(A)=det(A-XT_n)$